# Base de datos para un punto de venta en sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una base de datos para un punto de venta. Mi problema es el siguiente:

¡La tabla `detalle` y la tabla `factura` están relacionadas!

En la tabla `detalle` tengo: `cantidad | precio  | importe`

Y en la tabla `factura` tengo: `Num_factura  | fecha  | total`

Lo que quiero es que las suma de los importes se guarden en la columna `Total` de la tabla `factura`.

He tratado de hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
update fe set fe.Total = fe.Total + sum ( ed.Importe)  from Entrada_detalle ed inner join
Fact_entrada fe on ed.NumFact_Entrada = fe.NumFact_entrada where fe.NumFact_entrada = 2015
```

Comment: Los valores calculados como norma no se guardan en base para ahorrar espacio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al terminar de insertar los detalles, puedes lanzar la siguiente actualización:

```
update Factura
   set Total = (select sum(Detalle.Importe)
                  from Detalle
                 where Detalle.Num_factura = Factura.Num_factura
               )
 where Num_factura = 'A 123';
```

Esta actualiza el total de una factura específica con la sumatoria del importe de todos sus detalles (los que existan en ese momento en la DB).

Dicho esto, generalmente desaconsejo almacenar valores derivados en una base de datos transaccional; esto suele ser la fuente de errores y dolores de cabeza en sistemas en producción cuando la programación no es correcta.

---

Nota: He utilizado los nombres de tablas que das en la descripción de tu pregunta y no los que tienes en la consulta de ejemplo. Que sean diferentes es bastante confuso y no tengo idea cuales son los reales, ya te tocará a ti hacer los ajustes.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió.  Pero me aconseja que no guardar los totales de facturas ya es un error de sistema cuando esta en producción.                              Pues pienso sacar el total de los importe en el reporte. Si estoy correcto o no déjame saber.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió.....  Veo que  me aconseja  no guardar los totales de facturas ya es un error de sistema cuando esta en producción.                              Pues pienso sacar el total de los importe en el reporte. Si estoy correcto o no, déjame saber.

Comment: No digo que guardar el total sea un error, digo que puede ser una fuente de errores, porque lo he visto. Al final, son varias consideraciones a tomar para decidir guardarlo o no, por ejemplo, la complejidad de los cálculos para llegar a un resultado. Si los cálculos son sencillos, como parece aquí, y el volumen de datos no es tan alto, puede ser mejor calcularlo siempre que sea necesario. Un saludo.